# What is this slug-like creature?

Tags: identification, slugs

Can anyone identify this slug-like creature? Is it harmful?

[image: slug-like creature]

Note: this photograph was taken in Pennsylvania, U.S.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Appears to be some leopard slugs (Limax maximus). Can't be 100% sure since you didn't include the area the slugs were found but for the UK or North America it'd be right. They mostly eat rotten vegetation and potentially other slugs. It is not considered a pest and some consider them useful since they do eat some pest slug species.

Comment: You have the right identification, but it is considered a pest by some. "It also eats young crops faster than they can grow and so is listed as a major agricultural pest by state departments of agriculture in the US from Florida to Oregon." - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limax_maximus)

Comment: we call them tiger slugs in the UK - not pests at all and god do they move quick! consider them as goodies and don't use anything that can kill them- their more good than harm. (only an office worker would think all slugs are bad!)